# Video tag HTML5 not displaying to video

Tags: html, video, html5-video

what i'm currently is to have the user entering a link of a video. it gets stored in the database, I retrieve it, put it in a video tag to display it again to the user. My issue is that does not get displayed, appears as a video but when i click play nothing gets played and time is  00:00.

my code:

```
<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPyAQQklc1s" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnXO5mPtCkY">
</iframe>
```

Comment: not working, a white bordered  square is displayed only

Comment: do you think the issue is my browser?? i'm using chrome, and even on w3s run i can't see a thing!

Comment: Can you add a demo ??

Comment: can the demo be added from here? where?

Comment: the <object> tag actually worked on my page, but idk it's not working with the video i want to try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166186/discussion-between-anzil-khan-and-yara-binsaif).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9-kU7gfuFA';
preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $url, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
$width = '800px';
$height = '450px';?>


<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="<?php echo $width ?>" height="<?php echo $height ?>"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: yes i am using html5, the html5 version works with your video! but when i put this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnXO5mPtCkY **it does not work**

Comment: you need to use Embed Video URL

Comment: so the link needs to be copied from the iframe tag that youtube generates? I'm looking for the eassiest way to find the right link so that it can be easy to explain to the user

Comment: then you have to develop function for it wait a moment

Comment: USe my updated code just you need to change URL daynamicakly

Comment: then develop the same function with C#

Comment: what does the id refer to btw?

Comment: and the function can only be used with iframe? i wish to use it with object tag since it's the only one that worked with me

Comment: The generated URL will work with object tag  id is nothing here just you can use it if you want

Comment: how about preg match? wht is it taking $matches?

Comment: $matches retrun this Array ( [0] => ?v=u9-kU7gfuFA             and      [1] => u9-kU7gfuFA )

Answer (score -1):

the source attribute (src)  need to point a file location, the example in you question points to a web page (youtube). that is why it does not work. if the user is going to be passing youtube urls then you should follow the answer of Anzil khaN and use an iframe.

(EDIT)

I'm new so i can't add a comment i hope you can see this edit...

maybe is not working for you because you are using the "normal" youtube url (https://www.youtube.com/?watch=sjhBWhUl8Io), you need to format the url the user is passing to you so it be like this https://www.youtube.com/embed/sjhBWhUl8Io and you need to test it in a web server even if its just your local web server.  if you try opening just a .html directly in your browser is not going to work